# Set the FROM name of a mailinglist list in mailman3

Tags: mailman

Iam using mailman3 and I just want to set a FROM name for my lists. Currently the FROM for lists for example the welcome mail etc. is just the mailaddress like LISTNAME@lists.example.com but I would like to have it like `My List <listname@lists.example.com>`. I could not find the correct setting here:

https://docs.mailman3.org/projects/mailman/en/latest/src/mailman/config/docs/config.html#schema-cfg

to achieve that and hope there is a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

The mailing list display name is not used when sending service emails (like the welcome email). Also, they are being sent from addresses like `listname-request@lists.example.com` rather than from the main list's address.

Certain emails like (un)subscription notifications might be sent from an email defined in the [site-owner](https://docs.mailman3.org/projects/mailman/en/latest/src/mailman/config/docs/config.html#site-owner) parameter, but they are for list owners, not regular members.

Comment: I dont really understand that. `site_owner` might be used for user account service mails. But as you say, I want all those `listname-request@` `listname-bounces@` or `listname-bounces@` to show a real name instead of just the mail address

Comment: @Asara It's not possible with the current Mailman 3 code, but you can submit a feature request at https://gitlab.com/mailman/mailman/-/issues